# Get document id if it exists or insert it and return inserted document id if it does not exist

Tags: php, mongodb

I use MongoDB together with PHP. I want to get id of document if it exists or insert a new document then return the id of inserted document.

My `tags` collection like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "57b4e71b4535e71816816183",
        "tag": "tag1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "57b4e71b4535e7181681612b",
        "tag": "tag2" 
    }
]
```

I want to search by tag and get its id or insert it if does not exist. Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)** update operation that has the options `new` and `upsert` set to true. The `new` option set to true will return a single document with with the modifications made on the update.

With the specified `upsert` option set to true, **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)** either creates a new document if no documents match the query or updates a single document that matches the query.

The following mongo shell example demonstrates this:

```
var doc = { "tag": "tag3" };
var retval = db.tags.findAndModify({
    "query": doc,
    "update": { "$set": doc },
    "new": true, 
    "upsert": true
});    
printjson(retval._id)
```

---

The equivalent PHP **[code](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php)** follows:

```
$m = new Mongo;
$col = $m->selectDB("test")->tags;
$doc = array("tag" => "tag3");

$retval = $col->findAndModify(
    $doc,
    array("$set" => $doc),
    null,
    array(
        "upsert" => true,
        "new" => true,
    )
);

var_dump($retval);
```